# operator+() choose rvalue reference variation instead of const lvalue variation

Tags: c++, templates, operators, move-semantics

I am trying to understand what is happening in the following code.
It just an addition of 2 `std::array` and I assume that the output is:

> C1 = const C1& + const C2&

Instead it is:

> C1&& = C1&& + C2&&

Clearly, `ar` and `arr` are not temporaries.

What is wrong here, and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1//inline typename std::enable_if<is_densevector<C1>::value && is_densevector<C2>::value, C1>::type
operator+(const C1 &v1, const C2 &v2) { cout << "C1 = const C1& + const C2&" << endl; C1 r; return r; }
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C2//typename std::enable_if<is_densevector<C1>::value && is_densevector<C2>::value, C2>::type
&&operator+(const C1 &v1, C2 &&v2) { cout << "C2&& = const C1& + C2&&" << endl; return v2; }
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1//inline typename std::enable_if<is_densevector<C1>::value && is_densevector<C2>::value, C1>::type
&&operator+(C1 &&v1, const C2 &v2) { cout << "C1&& = C2&& + const C2&" << endl; return v1; }
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1//inline typename std::enable_if<is_densevector<C1>::value && is_densevector<C2>::value, C1>::type
&&operator+(C1 &&v1, C2 &&v2) { cout << "C1&& = C1&& + C2&&" << endl; return v1; }

int main()
{
    std::array<double,3> ar{1,2,3}, arr{3,2,1};
    ar + arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`&&` when used for a template parameter will collapse to `&` if the parameter is an lvalue, so the last definition becomes

```
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1& operator+(C1& v1, C2& v2);
```

The compiler will prefer this over

```
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1 operator+(const C1 &v1, const C2 &v2)
```

(or any of the others) as your arrays aren't `const`.

Comment: @Chameleon To be honest it sounds like you need to rethink your strategy, creating an `operator+` that can potentially match every type sounds like it's asking for trouble. Defining the template parameters in the context of `std::array`s will eliminate reference collapsing. There's also the fact that adding two arrays together is already an odd thing to do in itself, if I were to come across this code I wouldn't really be able to know what it does without looking at the definition, are you adding the elements together? Are you returning a new array with one array appended to the other?

Comment: I was used `class DenseVector : public container<arithmetic>` until now, and I experiment on something new, direct with containers. As the comments (in code) say, `container<arithmetic>` used like densevectors in a namespace, so addition `array<double,5> + vector<double>` is ok (with equal size assertion).

Comment: This is usually done using iterators, here's one example http://pastebin.com/YTGcYbbr